# implementação de codigo

Tags: c

Eu e um colega somo iniciantes em programação e estamos construindo um jogo em que precisamos utilizar lista encadeada. Ele ficou responsável por criar um menu do jogo utilizando lista encadeada e eu por criar o jogo. So que agora precisamos unir os códigos e acabou que não estamos conseguindo.

Preciso de uma mega ajuda de vocês para saber como faço para o jogo se comporte da seguinte maneira. No Menu criado o usuário vai inserir as palavras na lista utilizando a opção 1, apos as palavras serem inseridas o usuário entra na opção 4 e o jogo faz um Random das palavras inseridas e coloca no jogo para ser descoberta.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>
struct no
{
char info[15];
struct no*prox;
};
typedef struct no Lista;
void jogo() { 
char palavra[25],letra[25],lacuna[25]; 
int vida=6,x=0,i,u,total=0,cont=0; 


printf("                    ******************************");
printf("\n                            JOGO DA FORCA \n");
printf("                    ******************************\n");

printf("\n                             BOM JOGO\n\n");

printf("\nDIGITE A PALAVRA E TECLE ENTER PARA CONTINUAR");
printf("\n\nPALAVRA: ");

gets(palavra); 
fflush(stdin);

system("cls");

for(i=0;i<strlen(palavra);i++) 
{ 
lacuna[i]='X'; 
total++;
cont++;
} 

while(vida>0) 
{ 

printf("\nA PALAVRA COMTEM %i LETRAS\n",total);
printf("\nLETRAS RESTANTES: %i\n",cont);


printf("\n%s\n",lacuna); 
printf("\nENTRE COM UMA LETRA: "); 
gets(letra); 
system("cls");

for(i=0;i<strlen(palavra);i++) 
{ 
for(u=0;u<strlen(palavra);u++){
if(letra[u]==palavra[i]) 
{ 
lacuna[i]=palavra[i]; 
x++; 
cont--;
}
} 
} 

if(cont==0){
printf("PARABENS! VOCE VENCEU!");   
printf("\nACERTOU A PALAVRA %s", palavra);
}

if(x==0) 
{ 
vida--; 
printf("\nVOCE PERDEU UMA VIDA!\nVOCE TEM %d VIDA(S) 
RESTANTES\n\n",vida); 

} 
 x = 0;
}

printf("\n\nVC FOI ENFORCADO, Fim de jogo!\n\n\nPALAVRA SECRETA: 
%s",palavra);

printf("\n\n***********************\n\n");
printf("* JOGO DA FORCA *\n\n");
printf(" ___ \n");
printf(" | | \n");
printf(" | O  \n");
printf(" |/|\ \n");
printf(" | |  \n");
printf(" |/ \  \n");
printf(" |______ \n");
printf("\n**********************\n");

getchar(); 
getchar(); 
}
void cria (Lista **L)
{
*L=NULL;
}
void Ins_Inicio (Lista **L, char v[15])
{
Lista *p = (Lista *) calloc (1, sizeof(Lista));
 strcpy(p->info, v); 
p->prox=*L;
*L = p;
}
void imprime (Lista *L)
{
Lista*p;
p=L;
while (p != NULL)
{
printf("%s-->", p->info);
p=p->prox;
}
printf("NULL\n");
}
void jogar (Lista *L)
{
int num, total_nos=0;
Lista *p;
 p=L;
while (p!=NULL)
{
total_nos++;
p=p->prox;
}

int rand();
num = rand()+ (total_nos)+1;
while (p != NULL)
{ 
}}
main()
{
char palavra[25],letra[25],lacuna[25]; 
int vida=6,x,i; 

 Lista *L;
 int op, ret, fim;
 char val[15];
 cria(&L); 
 do 
 {
 int clrscr();
puts("1 - Insere palavras no INICIO da lista");
puts("2 - Remove palavras da lista");
puts("3 - IMPRIMIR a lista");
puts("4 - Jogar");
puts("5 - Sair");
puts("\nDigite a opcao desejada");
scanf("%d", &op);

switch(op)
{
case 1: puts("Digite o valor a ser inserido:");
    fflush(stdin);
    gets(val);
    Ins_Inicio(&L,val);
    break;

case 2: puts("Digite o valor a ser removido");
    fflush(stdin);  
    gets(val);

    break;
case 3: imprime(L);
    getch();
    break;
case 4: jogar(L);
    jogo();
    break;
}
}
while(op!=5);
 }
```

Comment: Segue uma recoemndação offtoic: se vocês querem aprender "C" - aguentem firmes no caminhque escolheram. Se quiserem aprender "programação" e faer isso criando programas tipo joguinhos que sejam jogáveis no caminho - recomento usar uma outra linguagem - de mais "alto nível" (isso não é pejorativo, é só uma forma de classificar as linguagens) - como Python, Javascript, ou Ruby.

Comment: Discordo @jsbueno. Fazer um jogo para uma linguagem que você está aprendendo é uma ótima forma de testar seu conhecimento.

Comment: Oi Francisco - então você concorda comigo - veja  o que eu escrevi: "se vocês querem aprender C, continuem nesse caminho.". A minha observação é para se eles quiserem aprender a programar códigos do tipo desse jogo, mas podendo ser com uma linguagem que facilite isso.

Comment: @jsbueno É mais fácil se tornar PP ou PC do que estudar C!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No seu caso, você colocou o  seu código todo na `main`, o que é funcional, mas é errado. Para juntar os 2 códigos, você pode criar um método no código do seu amigo com o seu código inteiro e chamalo apartir do `switch`.

```
switch(op)
{
case 1: puts("Digite o valor a ser inserido:");
    fflush(stdin);
    gets(val);
    Ins_Inicio(&L,val);
    break;
case 2: puts("Digite o valor a ser removido");
    fflush(stdin);  
    gets(val);
    break;
case 3: imprime(L);
    getch();
    break;
case 4: jogar(L);
    jogo(); //Aqui seria onde você chamaria o seu método.
    break;
}
```

Para pegar uma palavra aleatória que está no struct, você pode utilizar o `rand()` desta forma:

```
Lista L; 
pergunta = rand() % sizeof(L.info);
```

Caso tenha dificuldades para fazer isso, comente abaixo que eu posso lhe ajudar.

EDIT: Código pronto abaixo. (Está desorganizado porque peguei o seu como base.)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>
struct no
{
char info[15];
struct no*prox;
};
typedef struct no Lista;
void jogo() { 
char palavra[25],letra[25],lacuna[25]; 
int vida=6,x=0,i,u,total=0,cont=0; 


printf("                    ******************************");
printf("\n                            JOGO DA FORCA \n");
printf("                    ******************************\n");

printf("\n                             BOM JOGO\n\n");

printf("\nDIGITE A PALAVRA E TECLE ENTER PARA CONTINUAR");
printf("\n\nPALAVRA: ");

gets(palavra); 
fflush(stdin);

system("cls");

for(i=0;i<strlen(palavra);i++) 
{ 
lacuna[i]='X'; 
total++;
cont++;
 } 

while(vida>0) 
{ 

printf("\nA PALAVRA COMTEM %i LETRAS\n",total);
printf("\nLETRAS RESTANTES: %i\n",cont);


printf("\n%s\n",lacuna); 
printf("\nENTRE COM UMA LETRA: "); 
gets(letra); 
system("cls");

for(i=0;i<strlen(palavra);i++) 
{ 
for(u=0;u<strlen(palavra);u++){
if(letra[u]==palavra[i]) 
{ 
lacuna[i]=palavra[i]; 
x++; 
cont--;
}
} 
} 

if(cont==0){
printf("PARABENS! VOCE VENCEU!");   
printf("\nACERTOU A PALAVRA %s", palavra);
}

if(x==0) 
{ 
vida--; 
printf("\nVOCE PERDEU UMA VIDA!\nVOCE TEM %d VIDA(S) 
RESTANTES\n\n",vida); 

} 
 x = 0;
}

  printf("\n\nVC FOI ENFORCADO, Fim de jogo!\n\n\nPALAVRA SECRETA: 
%s",palavra);

  printf("\n\n***********************\n\n");
  printf("* JOGO DA FORCA *\n\n");
  printf(" ___ \n");
  printf(" | | \n");
  printf(" | O  \n");
  printf(" |/|\ \n");
  printf(" | |  \n");
  printf(" |/ \  \n");
  printf(" |______ \n");
  printf("\n**********************\n");

  getchar(); 
  getchar(); 
  }
void cria (Lista **L)
{
*L=NULL;
}
void Ins_Inicio (Lista **L, char v[15])
{
Lista *p = (Lista *) calloc (1, sizeof(Lista));
strcpy(p->info, v); 
p->prox=*L;
*L = p;
}
void imprime (Lista *L)
{
Lista*p;
p=L;
while (p != NULL)
{
    printf("%s-->", p->info);
    p=p->prox;
}
printf("NULL\n");
}
void jogar (Lista *L)
{
int num, total_nos=0;
Lista *p;
p=L;
while (p!=NULL)
{
  total_nos++;
  p=p->prox;
}

  int rand();
  num = rand()+ (total_nos)+1;
 while (p != NULL)
 { 
 }}
main()
{
char palavra[25],letra[25],lacuna[25]; 
int vida=6,x,i; 

 Lista *L;
 int op, ret, fim;
 char val[15];
 cria(&L); 
 do
{
int clrscr();
    puts("1 - Insere palavras no INICIO da lista");
    puts("2 - Remove palavras da lista");
    puts("3 - IMPRIMIR a lista");
    puts("4 - Jogar");
    puts("5 - Sair");
    puts("\nDigite a opcao desejada");
    scanf("%d", &op);

    switch(op)
    {
    case 1: puts("Digite o valor a ser inserido:");
        fflush(stdin);
        gets(val);
        Ins_Inicio(&L,val);
        break;

    case 2: puts("Digite o valor a ser removido");
        fflush(stdin);  
        gets(val);

        break;
    case 3: imprime(L);
        getch();
        break;
    case 4: jogar(L);
        jogo();
        break;
    }
}
while(op!=5);
}
```

Comment: Não entendi muito bem a sua explicação. Gostaria sim de uma ajuda melhor.

Comment: Só copiar e colar.

Comment: Bom dia @Francisco, acabei de testar a sua resposta e percebi que o jogo não esta acontecendo da forma esperada. Ver se vc tem como me ajudar. Gostaria de que o jogo se comportasse da seguinte maneira. No Menu criado o usuário vai inserir as palavras na lista utilizando a opção 1, apos as palavras serem inseridas o usuário entra na opção 4 e o jogo faz um Random das palavras inseridas e coloca no jogo para ser descoberta. Eu testei seu código e infelizmente não funcionou como esperado. Agradeço se puder continuar ajudando.

Comment: Eu nem sei muito de C, estou ajudando com o conhecimento que tenho em C#. Marque a resposta como correta e especifique mais o que está acontecendo atualmente no programa, quando eu chegar em casa eu posso te ajudar.

Comment: Editei minha resposta com uma maneira de pegar a palavra aleatória.

Answer (score 0):

A coisa mais importante quando se cria um programa em partes, cada parte por uma pessoa diferente, como vocês estão fazendo, é estabelecer entre vocês qual vai ser a *interface* entre o código dos dois: isto é, como o código de um vai se comunicar com o código do outro.

Neste caso, o seu colega fez um menu que vai iniciar o jogo e lidar com a lista de palavras (cadastro, remoção, e impressão) enquanto você ficou responsável pelo jogo propriamente dito. Então a única coisa que você precisa dele é a palavra a usar, e ele não precisa de nada de você.  Então sugiro que ele chame uma função `jogar()` passando a palavra escolhida como parâmetro e recebendo `void`, isto é, nada:

```
void
jogar(char palavra[TAM_MAX_PALAVRA]);
```

Você implementa a função `jogar()` e ele a chama na hora correta lá na opção 4.

Note que pus no tamanho do vetor que a `jogar()` recebe o identificador `TAM_MAX_PALAVRA`, em vez de 15 ou 25. Essa é uma constante de preprocessador (que vamos definir abaixo) que te permite garantir que todas as partes que precisam lidar com palavras vão lidar com o mesmo tamanho de vetor, vetores de tamanho `TAM_MAX_PALAVRA`. A definição dele é:

```
#define TAM_MAX_PALAVRA 25
```

Para sacramentar a sua interface, pegamos as duas definições acima e pomos num arquivo chamado `jogo.h`, o seu arquivo cabeçalho para o jogo:

```
#ifndef DEFINI_JOGO_H
#define DEFINI_JOGO_H

#define TAM_MAX_PALAVRA 25
extern void
jogar(char palavra[TAM_MAX_PALAVRA]);

#endif
```

Vamos então pegar o código do seu colega e pôr no arquivo `menu.c`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>
#include "jogo.h"

/* Tipos de dados */

struct no {
    char info[TAM_MAX_PALAVRA];
    struct no * prox;
};

typedef struct no Lista;

/* Funções de manipulação de listas encadeadas */

void
Ins_Inicio(Lista **L, char v[TAM_MAX_PALAVRA]) {
    Lista *p = calloc(1, sizeof(Lista));
    strcpy(p->info, v); 
    p->prox = *L;
    *L = p;
}

void
imprime (Lista *L) {
    Lista *p;
    p = L;
    while (p != NULL) {
        printf("%s-->", p->info);
        p = p->prox;
    }
}

void
apagar(Lista ** L, char chave[TAM_MAX_PALAVRA]) {
    printf("TODO: me implemente\n");
}

char *
escolher_palavra_ao_acaso(Lista * L) {
   /* a implementação será feita abaixo */
}

/* funções para tratar do menu */

int
menu() {
    int resultado;
    clrscr();
    puts(
        " *****************\n"
        " * JOGO DA FORCA *\n"
        " *****************\n\n"
        "1 - Insere palavras no INICIO da lista"\n"
        "2 - Remove palavras da lista\n"
        "3 - IMPRIMIR a lista\n"
        "4 - Jogar\n"
        "5 - Sair\n\n"
        "Digite a opcao desejada"
    );
    while (scanf("%d", &resultado) < 1) {
        puts("Não entendi");
    }
    return resultado;
}

int
main(void) {
    int opcao = 0;
    Lista * L;
    char val[TAM_MAX_PALAVRA];

    srand(time(NULL));
    do {
        opcao = menu();
        switch (opcao) {
            case 1:
                puts("Digite o valor a ser inserido:");
                fflush(stdin);
                fgets(val, TAM_MAX_PALAVRA, stdin);
                Ins_Inicio(&L,val);
                break;
            case 2:
                puts("Digite o valor a ser removido");
                fflush(stdin);  
                fgets(val, TAM_MAX_PALAVRA, stdin);
                apagar(&L,val);
                break;
            case 3:
                imprime(L);
                break;
            case 4:
                jogar(escolher_palavra_ao_acaso(L));
                break;
            case 5:
                puts("Saindo...");
                break;
            default:
                puts("Opção inválida");
                break;
        }
    } while (opcao != 5);

    return 0;
}
```

Como pode ver, o arquivo `jogo.h` foi incluído usando aspas, e não menor-que e maior-que, para que o compilador procure pelo arquivo no mesmo diretório dos arquivos .c e não no diretório onde ficam `stdio.h` e colegas. Também nós quebramos as funções maiores em várias pequenas com nomes descritivos: por exemplo, tem uma `menu()` que mostra o menu, recebe a opção e a entrega como valor de retorno para que a `main()` não precise se preocupar com isso; e a `jogar()` recebe uma palavra que `escolher_palavra_ao_acaso()` vai receber.

Vamos implementar então `escolher_palavra_ao_acaso()`:

```
char *
escolher_palavra_ao_acaso(Lista * L) {
    int num_palavras = 0, i = 0;
    Lista * p;

    /* Contar o número de palavras atual */
    for (p = L; p != NULL; num_palavras ++, p = p->prox);
    /* n vai receber um número aleatório entre 0 e num_palavras - 1 */
    n = rand() % num_palavras;
    /* começando do princípio da lista, andar n passos */
    for (p = L; n > 0; n --, p = p->prox);

    return n->info;
}
```

Quanto ao jogo, você cria um outro arquivo `teste.c` para poder testar o desenvolvimento da sua parte:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "jogo.h"

int
main(void) {
    jogar("itaquaquecetuba");
}
```

E finalmente a implementação da rotina `jogar()` em `jogo.c`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include "jogo.h"

/* uma struct para guardar todas as informações sobre o estado do jogo */
struct estado {
    char * palavra;
    int tam_palavra;
    char lacunas[TAM_MAX_PALAVRA];
    int vidas;
    int faltam;
};

int
testar_letra(struct estado * e, char c) {
    int i;
    int resultado = 0;

    /* transforma letras maiúsculas em minúsculas */
    if (c >='A' && c <='Z') c -= 32;
    /* verifica se é uma letra válida*/
    if (c < 'a' || c > 'z') return resultado;
    /* procura por c em palavra; onde houver, preenche a lacuna correspondente */
    for (i = 0; i < e->tam_palavra; i ++) {
        if (e->palavra[i] == c) {
            resultado = 1;
            faltam --;
            e->lacunas[i] = e->palavra[i];
        }
    }

    return resultado;
}

void
jogar(char * palavra) {
    int i;
    struct estado e;
    char c;

    /* inicializa o estado do jogo */
    e.palavra = palavra;
    e.vidas = 6;
    e.faltam = e.tam_palavra = strlen(palavra);
    for (i = 0; i < e.tam_palavra; i ++)
        e.lacunas[i] = 'X';
    e.lacunas[i] = '\0';

    clrscr();
    while (e.vidas > 0) {
        printf("\nA PALAVRA COMTEM %d LETRAS\n"
               "\nLETRAS RESTANTES: %d\n",e.tam_palavra, e.faltam);
        printf("\n%s\n", e.lacunas);
        printf("\nENTRE COM UMA LETRA: ");
        /* limpa o buffer */
        fflush(stdin);
        c = getchar();
        if (! testa_letra(&e, c)) {
            e.vidas--;
            printf("\nVOCE PERDEU UMA VIDA!\n"
                   "VOCE TEM %d VIDA(S) RESTANTES\n\n",vida);
            if (e.vidas == 0) {
                printf("\n\n"
                       "VC FOI ENFORCADO, Fim de jogo!"
                       "\n\n\n"
                       "PALAVRA SECRETA: %s",palavra);

                printf("\n\n***********************\n\n"
                       "* JOGO DA FORCA *\n\n"
                       " ___ \n"
                       " | | \n"
                       " | O  \n"
                       " |/|\ \n"
                       " | |  \n"
                       " |/ \  \n"
                       " |______ \n"
                       "\n**********************\n");
                return;
            }
        } else if (e.faltam == 0) {
            printf("PARABENS! VOCE VENCEU!"
                   "\nACERTOU A PALAVRA %s", palavra);
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Aí, na hora de compilar o jogo, você compila os dois módulos `jogo.c` e `menu.c` juntos. Como você deve estar usando uma IDE, não tem necessidade de comentar sobre opções de linha de comando, mas é super simples. Compila `jogo.c` e `menu.c` para o jogo completo, ou `jogo.c` e `teste.c` para testar só a sua parte.

Comment: Amigo, somos iniciantes e ficou meio confuso. Tem como colocar o código pronto de cada arquivo? estamos iniciando o curso e começamos a estudar juntos. Agradecido pela ajuda.@Wtrmute

Comment: Os códigos estão separados por arquivo. O único trabalho que você teria seria inserir a implementação da função `escolher_palavra_ao_acaso()` por sobre a _stub_ que está onde ela deveria ir. Eu sei que a resposta é comprida; maior que provavelmente deveria ser. Mas não fique com preguiça de ler, porque C é uma linguagem que não perdoa a falta de atenção...